# validate xml schema generated manually

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, xsd, mondrian

I am trying to develop a app : *Multidimensional analysis application with JSF/J2EE*, I generate a Schema xml file and now i want to validate it with [mondrian.xsd](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pentaho/mondrian/master/lib/mondrian.xsd) this my generated code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Schema description="test shcema description" name="First Schema9">
    <Cube cache="true" 
          caption="code here" 
          description="cubeInSchema" 
          enabled="true" 
          name="First Cube7"/>
    <Parameter defaultValue="admin" 
               description="parameter role" 
               modifiable="true" 
               name="param name" 
               type="String"/>
</Schema>
```

but i get this error in validation :

```
**cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of the element "Cube" is not complete. One of the values ​​"{Annotations, Table, View}" is expected.**
```

==> but i don't think that we should have a {`Annotations`, `Table`, `View`} in each cube. I don't know how I should validate my mondrian schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [mondrian.xsd](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pentaho/mondrian/master/lib/mondrian.xsd) XSD the `Cube` element is declared as:

```
<xsd:element name="Cube" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    ...
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Annotations" type="Annotations" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:group ref="FactTable" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                ...
            </xsd:group>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element name="DimensionUsage" type="DimensionUsage"/>
                <xsd:element name="Dimension" type="PrivateDimension"/>
            </xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="Measure" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                ...
```

From there it's declared that a chid `<Annotations>` element is optional (`minOccurs="0"`) *but* elements from the `FactTable` group, a `<Dimension>` *or* `<DimensionUsage>` and a `<Measure>` elements *must* be present, in that order.

Searching for the `FactTable` group you find:

```
<xsd:group name="FactTable">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="Table" type="Table"/>
        <xsd:element name="View" type="View"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:group>
```

which means that the elements that are mandatory in the `<Cube>` are `<View>` (or `<Table>`), `<Dimension>` (or `<DimensionUsage>`) and `<Measure>`. If they are not present, your instance will not validate.

Besides that, there is an *order* enforced in the `<Schema>` sequence: `<View>` must appear *after* `<Parameter>` (and not as in your example).

I generated a minimum validating file from the `mondrian.xsd` schema, based on your file. Considering the options `Dimension` and `View`, all these are mandatory:

```
<Schema description="test shcema description" name="First Schema9">
    <Parameter defaultValue="admin" 
               description="parameter role" 
               modifiable="true"
               name="param name" 
               type="String"/>
    <Cube cache="true" 
          caption="code here" 
          description="cubeInSchema" 
          enabled="true"
          name="First Cube7">

        <View alias="aaa">
            <SQL dialect="sss"></SQL>
        </View>
        <Dimension name="bbb">
            <Annotations>
                <Annotation></Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Hierarchy hasAll="false">
                <Level name="ccc"></Level>
            </Hierarchy>
        </Dimension>
        <Measure name="ddd" aggregator="max"/>
    </Cube>
</Schema>
```

Comment: have u a idea how can i make solution to validate my schema (lib or API...) for J2EE ?

Comment: @user3685698, helderdarocha answered the question you asked quite thoroughly.  Consider asking your new question separately.